# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar resultados de una consulta sin que se repitan?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy buscando las palabras SECURITY, UPDATE Y MICROSOFT mediante `strrpos`. Al encontrarlas las imprimo, pero necesito imprimir registros únicos y que no se repitan.

Pongo el ejemplo de los resultados que muestra, se repite el registro 3 y no quiero que suceda eso. Se me ocurre un `array` pero no sé utilizarlos bien.
Debo buscar 10 palabras más. Espero me den ideas.

```
$query_ocs = "SELECT * FROM softwares WHERE ID > 1 ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_ocs);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $nmz = $row['NAME'];
  $idz  = $row['ID'];

  #PALABRAS A BUSCAR
  $cadena_de_texto = 'Update';
  $cadena_buscada = $nmz;
  $posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_buscada,$cadena_de_texto);
  if ($posicion_coincidencia === false) {
  }else {$Update=$nmz;}

  $cadena_de_texto = 'Security';
  $cadena_buscada = $nmz;
  $posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_buscada,$cadena_de_texto);
  if ($posicion_coincidencia === false) {
  }else {$Security=$nmz;}

  $cadena_de_texto = 'Microsoft';
  $cadena_buscada = $nmz;
  $posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_buscada,$cadena_de_texto);
  if ($posicion_coincidencia === false) {
  }else {$Microsoft=$nmz;}

echo $Update . "<br>";
echo $Security . "<br>";
echo $Microsoft . "<br>";
}
?>


BASE DE DATOS:
| ID  | NAME                |
| 1   | Update KB8457       |
| 2   | Microsoft Tools v1  |
| 3   | Security Update     |
| 4   | Security Avast      |
| 5   | Antivirus Free      |

RESULTADO QUE ARROJA
1   | Update KB8457
2   | Microsoft Tools v1
3   | Security Update 
3   | Security Update 
4   | Security Avast
```

- RESULTADO QUE NECESITO ENCONTRAR
- 1   | Update KB8457
- 2   | Microsoft Tools v1
- 3   | Security Update
- 4   | Security Avast

Comment: Es necesario mostrar el ID?

Comment: jolsalazar - No necesariamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes manejar con menos código desde el SQL, el cual es muy bueno para filtrar y ordenar:

```
$palabras = array('Update','Security','Microsoft');
$query_ocs = "SELECT * FROM softwares WHERE ID > 1 AND ( name like '%".implode("%' or name like '%",$palabras)."%') ORDER BY ID DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_ocs);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   echo $row['ID'].' '.$row['NAME'].'<br>';
```

Simplemente usando los operadores `or` y `like`.

Comment: Como deberia de imprimirlo? ya coloque la consulta pero no me devuelve algun valor

Comment: La impresión depende de lo que necesites, agregué un loop de ejemplo.

Comment: Genio, me hiciste ahorrar demasiado código. esa no me la sabía

Answer (score 4):

Suponiendo que lo que intentas hacer es buscar sí las palabras están contenidas o no dentro, y no agrupándolas por base de datos.

Una forma para que no se te repita el resultado puede ser lo siguiente.

Básicamente, poner una condición si es que ya se encontró un resultado, no volver a mostrarlo, de esta forma ya no se repetiría.

```
$query_ocs = "SELECT * FROM softwares WHERE ID > 1 ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_ocs);
$palabras = [];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $nmz = $row['NAME'];
  $idz  = $row['ID'];

  #PALABRAS A BUSCAR
  $cadena_de_texto = 'Update';
  $cadena_buscada = $nmz;
  $posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_buscada,$cadena_de_texto);
  if ($posicion_coincidencia) {
    array_push($palabras, $nmz);
  }

  if($Update != ''){
    $cadena_de_texto = 'Security';
    $cadena_buscada = $nmz;
    $posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_buscada,$cadena_de_texto);
    if ($posicion_coincidencia) {
      array_push($palabras, $nmz);
    }
  }

  if($Update != '' && $Security != ''){
    $cadena_de_texto = 'Microsoft';
    $cadena_buscada = $nmz;
    $posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_buscada,$cadena_de_texto);
    if ($posicion_coincidencia) {
      array_push($palabras, $nmz);
    }
  }

}
// Imprimimos el array de palabras encontradas 
echo join('<br>', $palabras);
?>
```

Comment: Corrección, solo se muestran los que tienen Security Update, los registros omitidos se ven en blanco o  como saltos de linea

Comment: Perdon, me equivoque en el ultimo IF le puse un or y era un and, prueba y me comentas

Comment: Genio, me está funcionando, aunque me deja unos saltos de linea muy grandes, deja adaptarlo y me parece que serias Best Answer :)

Comment: Claro, el salto lo da, por que si o si estas escribiendo en cada vuelta del bucle, eso quiere decir, que si no encuentra un resultado, dará 3 `<br>`. Aprovechando el codigo, el `echo` ingresalo a la condicion de cada uno. O bien, guardas cada resultado en un array y despues lo muestras fuera del bucle. Opciones tienes! eso es lo bueno.

Comment: Podrías ayudarme con el array? no soy muy bueno usándolos. Aunque ya va tomando forma

Comment: Modifique la respuesta agregando una solucion con arreglos para mostrar los resultados.

Comment: Excelente jolsalazar, gracias Genio

Answer (score 4):

Puedes intentar una solucion elegante para php 7.4 mas o menos asi:

```
<?php

$query_ocs = "SELECT id, name FROM softwares WHERE ID > 1 ORDER BY ID DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_ocs);
$coincidences = [];
$wordsToFind = ['Update', 'Security', 'Microsoft'];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);

    $matches = array_filter($wordsToFind, fn($f) => strpos($name, $f) !== false);

    if ($matches){
        $coincidences[$id] = [
            'data' => ['name' => $name],
            'matches' => $matches
        ];
    }
}

foreach ($coincidences as $id => $data){
    $name = $data['data']['name'];
    $matches = implode(', ', $data['matches']);

    echo "$id - $name: $matches </ br>";
}

?>
```

Puedes cambiar la expresión `fn($f) => strpos($name, $f) !== false` si es que aun no usas php 7.4:

```
$matches = array_filter($wordsToFind, function($f) use($name){ 
    return strpos($name, $f) !== false;
});
```

Aunque para aclarar, si tienes 100 filas en tu base de datos, y tienes 10 términos para buscar, se harán 100 * 10 búsquedas y todo los costos de CPU que eso implica. Te recomiendo que tengas otra tabla llamada `Etiquetas` donde puedas asignarle a cada fila los correspondientes términos de interés, de la misma forma que StackOverflow lo hace. Por ejemplo con [`Php`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

Comment: No me funcionó bro :/
Tengo 7.1, y sustituí la linea que comentas pero no imprime nada

Comment: @EvilFearzZ creo que podría ser el [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php). Fíjate bien que `$id` y `$name` estén definidos, si no, cambia el extract por `$id  = $row['ID']; $name = $row['NAME'];` según los nombres de variables que tengas en la consulta SQL